# Deploying a java web application online

Tags: java, war, web-deployment, cloudbees

I have built a java web application on Eclipse. But i am naive in terms of making an application live i.e. deploy it online. I have tried using Cloudbees, and succeeded in deploying it at run@cloud there, but could not see it actually running. I haven't purchased any domain name as of now, therefore I would like to try it on any free domain first. If I want to make that application live, what would be the exact steps that I'll have to follow ?

Comment: I suppose u should buy a domain or hack one!

Comment: Have you tried on your own local server?

Comment: yes, it works on my local Apache Tomcat Server version 7.0.

Comment: also, by free domain, i mean a free sub-domain

Comment: @rishabh85, you can get a free (sub)domain (such as .tk, .co.cc, etc.) at http://www.getfreedomain.name. once you set the DNS records correctly, that should work with any hosting/cloud provider.

Comment: See this,
How to deploy Java web project WAR to a real website
https://youtu.be/J1pViMfR7RA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Redhat Openshift Cloud...

Redhat Openshift is a Cloud based service which provide PAAS(Platform As A Service) i.e. Use their Server and upload our Project.

Redhat Openshift also provides MySql , Postgre and MongoDB.

It Easy to understand, Simple to Configure and Auto-Scalable.

Redhat Openshift supports:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/24576260/Redhat%20Support.png

There are alternatives of Redhat Openshift - Google App Engine (GAE). But GAE restrict some of the class usages in Trial Verison.

Whereas Openshift have kept open and whatever user wants he can use and configure it.

Answer (score 5):

**Try [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/).**
They have a free trial as well.
PS: Works for me each time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have deployed successfully to RUN@cloud then your app is already running; there is no need to purchase a custom domain. If you log in to https://grandcentral.cloudbees.com/ and click on the *Apps* tab, you should see your new application listed; the *show in new window* link will open the live web page. (This will be http://appid.accountid.cloudbees.net/ where *appid* is whatever you chose when creating the app, and *accountid* is *rishabh85* or whatever your CloudBees login name is.)

You can also load this page directly from Eclipse, if using the CloudBees SDK (use http://eclipse.cloudbees.com/ to download or http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/07/getting-started-with-cloudbees-and.html for more information). Configure your account information, and open the CloudBees view (available from the CloudBees toolbar button), and you will see your running apps. A context menu item lets you open the selected app live in a web browser.

Comment: yes, you are right. but when i ran the default Hello World project as local app using cloudbees, it showed me Hello World as an output in the web browser as the application was expected to do. Now, I want that my project should behave the same way on cloud i.e. the same project should show the same output to anyone who accesses that link i.e. to public. Instead, it shows the page 'This application under development'. How can I see the actual output or will i be able to access it in this way only ? I am new to it.

Comment: Thanks it is solved now. I changed the jsp which loads from the default version.

Answer (score 1):

Try Google app engine. You can deploy your Web applications and you ll get a free sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

As I have small knowledge of working like this, its very easy. This is to inform you that its works like your own pc. In my last company they had a Windows server.. and Tomcat & MySQL was pre installed on that server. I just place my `.war` in the proper place & imported the blank DB.. and its starts working :)

Comment: yes, that is fine but i was looking for an exact answer i.e. which service to use to deploy the project online using .war or directly running app on their server so that i can see the output online itself.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [my blog posts](http://amirzucker.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/online-service-development-in-java-a-beginners-guide/) on creating a web service from scratch using Cloudbees.  It's a series of 7 posts that have everything you need in order to get your service up and running (including an opensource code base with almost everything you need already integrated)

If you just want the fastest way, checkout [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnCNJ5IYWFM).